# Can I specify default value?

Tags: c++, arrays

Why is it that for user defined types when creating an array of objects every element of this array is initialized with the default constructor, but when I create an array of a built-in type that isn't the case?

And second question: Is it possible to specify default value to be used while initializing elements in the array? Something like this (not valid):

```
char* p = new char[size]('\0');
```

And another question in this topic while I'm with arrays. I suppose that when creating an array of user defined type, every element of this array will be initialized with default value. Why is this?

If arrays for built in types do not initialize their elements with their defaults, why do they do it for User Defined Types?

Is there a way to avoid/circumvent this default construction somehow? It seems like bit of a waste if I for example have created an array with size 10000, which forces 10000 default constructor calls, initializing data which I will (later on) overwrite anyway.

I think that behaviour should be consistent, so either every type of array should be initialized or none. And I think that the behaviour for built-in arrays is more appropriate.

Comment: Seriously -- is it that difficult to write a standard English question? Is typing "elem." and "dflt ctor" all that much faster than "element" and "default constructor"? I have edited these things into their standard English counterparts to the best of my understanding, but you will get better answers in the future if others do not have to work hard to understand what your question is.

Comment: @atch: I edited that into my answer.

Comment: And seriously I don't think anyone has problems (except you of course) with understanding pretty common abbreviations like elem, elems, ctor, dtor and dflt ctor. Even you are using POD UDT etc.

Comment: @atch: There's a difference between using an acronym or initialism in  a comment (where you are limited in how long your text can be) and using one in a question.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563254/why-do-i-have-to-provide-default-ctor The solution I give last *may* be of use here, but I seriously doubt it's that bad to default construct an array, then go through and assign them all meaningful values.

Comment: @Billy's first answer Yes it is both mutch faster and less typing and just to show you little example: if I type the way I type (elem, dflt ctor) a hundred times I type 1200(one thousand two hundreds) characters less then I would have to type if I was typing the way you mentioned. So decide for yourself if 1200 chars less is worth of doing that and bear in mind that this is if I type those words just 100 times, taking a thousand gives you 12000 (twelfe thousands) which prooves that my way is definitely worth of doing that

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: That does not change the fact that it's incredibly rude and will make it more difficult to get answers. When answerers see that you're too lazy to properly ask a question, they feel too lazy to spend time writing you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something like this (not valid):

<s>As far as I know that is perfectly valid.</s>
Well not completely, but you can get a zero intialized character array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //The extra parenthesis on the end call the "default constructor"
    //of char, which initailizes it with zero.
    char * myCharacters = new char[100]();
    for(size_t idx = 0; idx != 100; idx++) {
        if (!myCharacters[idx])
            continue;
        std::cout << "Error at " << idx << std::endl;
        std::system("pause");
    }
    delete [] myCharacters;
    return 0;
}
```

This program produces no output.

> And another question in this topic while I'm with arrays. I suppose that when creating an array of user defined type and knowing the fact that every elem. of this array will be initialized with default value firstly why?

Because there's no good syntactic way to specialize each element allocated with new. You can avoid this problem by using a vector instead, and calling reserve() in advance. The vector will allocate the memory but the constructors will not be called until you push_back into the vector. You should be using vectors instead of user managed arrays anyway because new'd memory handling is almost always not exception safe.

> I think that behaviour should be consistent, so either every type of array should be initialized or none. And I think that the behaviour for built-in arrays is more appropriate.

Well if you can think of a good syntax for this you can write up a proposal for the standard -- not sure how far you'll get with that.

**Why is it that for user defined types when creating an array of objects every element of this array is initialized with the default constructor, but when I create an array of a built-in type that isn't the case?** and
**And another question in this topic while I'm with arrays. I suppose that when creating an array of user defined type, every element of this array will be initialized with default value. Why is this?**  and
**If arrays for built in types do not initialize their elements with their defaults, why do they do it for User Defined Types?**
Because a user defined type is never ever valid until its constructor is called. Built in types are always valid even if a constructor has not been called.

**And second question: Is it possible to specify default value to be used while initializing elements in the array? Something like this (not valid):**
Answered this above.

**Is there a way to avoid/circumvent this default construction somehow? It seems like bit of a waste if I for example have created an array with size 10000, which forces 10000 default constructor calls, initializing data which I will (later on) overwrite anyway.**
Yes, you can use a vector as I described above.

Comment: HOW did you compile this, that your saying that it's valid?

Comment: @atch: Sorry -- just realized that `char` does not provide a copy constructor like this. I have edited in an example that makes use of the default constructor syntax though, which initializes all the chars with zero.

Comment: And about syntax: I think syntax I've presented is quite ok.

Comment: @atch: You have provided no syntax. If you want to be able to construct an array with values, then you need to be able to provide as many constructor argument sets as there are values in the array. We're talking about small potatoes in any case -- 99.9% of the time the allocation time will be much longer than constructor execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for exactly what you've presented.

Comment: Can't agree with you on the last one. In my syntax char* p = new char[size](<params>); you can specify as many elems as you wish.

Comment: @atch: You run into difficulty when a constructor requires more than one argument. Rest assured, there is a reason no such syntax is in the standard. I have edited my above answer to answer some more of your specific questions (now that I've pieced apart your question). I hope that's helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

That's how built-in types work in C++. In order to initialize them you have to supply an explicit initializer. If you don't, then the object will remain uninitialized. This behavior is in no way specific to arrays. Standalone objects behave in exactly the same way.

One problem here is that when you are creating an array using `new[]`, you options for supplying an initializer (in the current version of the language) are very limited. In fact, the only initializer you can supply is the empty `()`

```
char* p = new char[size](); 
// The array is filled with zeroes
```

In case of `char` type (or any other scalar type), the `()` initializer will result in zero-initialization, which is incidentally what you tried to do.

Of course, if your desired default value in not zero, you are out of luck, meaning that you have to explicitly assign the default values to the elements of the `new[]`-ed array afterwards.

As for disabling the default constructor call for arrays of types with user-defined default constructor... well, there's no way to achieve that with ordinary `new[]`. However, you can do it by implementing your own array construction process (which is what `std::vector` does, for one example). You first allocate raw memory for the entire array, and then manually construct the elements one-by-one in any way you see fit. Standard library provides a number of primitive intended to be used specifically for that purpose. That includes `std::allocator` and functions like `uninitialized_copy`, `uninitialized_fill` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (unless you're using the new C++0x), C++ will call the constructor that takes no arguments e.g. `myClass::myClass()`. If you want to initialise it to something, implement a constructor like this that initialises your variables. e.g.

```
class myChar {
    public:
        myChar();

        char myCharVal;
};

myChar::myChar(): myCharVal('\0') {
}
```

Comment: This incurs a runtime penalty. Most classes/structs will always have different alignment rules than naked chars, even if it's not strictly necessary. For example, on x86 that class will have a width of 4 bytes rather than one.

Comment: Sorry I missed your edit. For your second question, if you don't initialise your variables in your custom class, it depends on the compiler as to what happens. Some compilers set variables to 0 if they're not specifially set by you (unless your tell them not to using compiler options such as optimisation), and in others it's the default not to do anything. Therefore, you can usually get away with it doing nothing if you set an array of 10,000 elements like that.

Comment: I believe (although I've never tried it myself) that you can use the #pragma pack setting to specify any padding the compiler should put in. I do know there's always a way to tightly pack your arrays if your classes are "Plain Old Data" (don't do anything fancy like virtual functions).

Comment: I'm using VS2010RC and it tells me that this code is invalid? What's going on?

Comment: I'm using GCC, and there's no errors. What's the error message?

Comment: @Warpspace: I'm using VS2010RC as well and I get no errors. I suspect a PEBKAC is on the loose :)

Comment: What on earth is PEBKAC stands for? @Billy I'm getting msg: A new initializer cannot be specified for an array.

Comment: @atch: **P** roblem **E** xists **B** etween **K** eyboard **A** nd **C** hair. I see no array in the above example code so I fail to see how you can be getting that message from Warpspace's code.

Comment: @Billy Thanks for explanaition. Nice one ;)

Comment: The array would be myChar* p = new myChar[size]; I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ philosophy is - don't pay for something you don't need.

And I think the behviour is pretty unified. If your UDT didn't have a default constructor, nothing would be run anyway and the behaviour would be the same as for built-in types (which don't have a default constructor).

Comment: Almost. All UDTs -- even POD types -- have a default constructor provided by the compiler. If it's just a POD struct then the default constructor does not need to do anything, but the issue is there nonetheless.

Comment: But it wont allow me to create an array of objects if I won't provide dflt ctor. And if the philosophy is that I shouldn't pay for what I don't need why do I have to pay for invoking dflt ctor?

Comment: "But it wont allow me to create an array of objects if I won't provide dflt ctor." <-- Yes, it will. Give me a sec and I'll edit that into my answer.

Comment: @atch: Found a better answer. You can create an array without default constructors if you use placement new. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that for user defined types when creating an array of objects every element of this array is initialized with the default constructor, but when I create an array of a built-in type that isn't the case?

But if the default constructor of an object does nothing then it is still not initialiized.

```
class X
{
     public:
         char y;
}
X* data = new X[size]; // defaut constructor called. But y is still undefined.
```

> And second question: Is it possible to specify default value to be used while initializing elements in the array? > Something like this (not valid):

Yes:

```
char                data1[size]  = { 0 };
std::vector<char>   data2(size,0);
char*               data3 = new char[size];
memset(data3,0,size);
```

> Is there a way to avoid/circumvent this default construction somehow? It seems like bit of a waste if I for example have created an array with size 10000, which forces 10000 default constructor calls, initializing data which I will (later on) overwrite anyway.

Yes. Use a std::vector.

You can reserve the space for all the elements you need without calling the constructor.

```
std::vector<char>    data4;
data4.reserve(size);
```